# Getting error as "Could not find artifact com.oracle:ojdbc6:jar:6.0.0 in central" while triggering build from JENKINS

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

I am trying to do build and deployment from a JENKINS job for my Spring Maven Project but getting below error:

```
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/oracle/ojdbc6/6.0.0/ojdbc6-6.0.0.pom
[WARNING] The POM for com.oracle:ojdbc6:jar:6.0.0 is missing, no dependency information available
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/oracle/ojdbc6/6.0.0/ojdbc6-6.0.0.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 11.942 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-09-16T23:17:15+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project SpringBootSmaple: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.springboot.practise:SpringBootSmaple:war:0.1: Could not find artifact com.oracle:ojdbc6:jar:6.0.0 in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
Build step 'Invoke top-level Maven targets' marked build as failure
Unable to deploy to IBM WebSphere Application Server, Build Result = FAILURE
Finished: FAILURE
```

I also installed ojdbc jar in maven by using below command:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=C:\Documents\SharedJars\ojdbc6.jar -DgroupId=com.oracle -DartifactId=ojdbc6 -Dversion=6.0.0 -Dpackaging=jar
```

But still getting the same error. Someone please guide.

Comment: are you executing `mvn install` directly on the Jenkins box? do you have a company repository? (like Nexus or assembla?)

Comment: Yes..I am doing clean install directly in Jenkins Job and No we don't have company repository yet.